# powershell cmdlet in c# - How to access AD objects in ProcessRecord

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am writing a Powershell module in C#. Some of the cmdlets process input from Microsofts AD Powershell module. I like to do something like this in Powershell:

```
Get-ADUser MyUser | New-MyCmdlet
```

So the AD user 'MyUser' is passed to my Cmdlet 'New-MyCmdlet'. MyUser is of type `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser`

The c# class would look as follows:

```
namespace MyCmdlet
{
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.New, "MyAdUserOperation")]
public class NewAdUserOperationCmdlet : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter(
        Mandatory = true,
        ValueFromPipeline = true,
        ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = true,
        HelpMessage = "ADUser object from AD to be stored on database.")]
    public object AdUser { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        base.ProcessRecord();

        if (AdUser != null)
        {
            // do something with the props, e.g:
            // var dn = AdUser.DistinguishedName;
            // var pwLastSet = AdUser.PasswordLastSet
            // etc.....
        }
    }
}
}
```

I declared the input parameter of type `object` because I do not know how to get `ADUser` in my project. So I can see a bit more in the debugger.... The commented code shows, what I'd like to do.

- Question 1: I do not find an assembly for `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser`. What do I need to add to my project?
- Question 2: If there is no assembly, how can I access all the properties of this ADUser object? In the debugger of VS 2015 I can see all props even all extended. But how can I access them??

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself by searching for a more general approach: How can I figure out, what I really get through the pipe? You usually get more complex things than just a string object.....

The solution is, that parameters in powershell are of type `PSObject` or `PSCustomObject`. See [MSDN Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

These classes have nice collections named `Members` and `Properties` which can be iterated.

For my above sample, I did the following:

1. Declared the parameter as PSObject instead of Object `public PSObject AdUser { get; set; }`
2. Iterated over `AdUser.Properties` to discover what is inside like such

   ```
       if (AdUser != null)
       {
           List<string> strList = new List<string>();
           var userProps = AdUser.Properties;
           foreach (var prop in userProps)
           {
               string data = String.Format("property: {0} | value: {1}", prop.Name, prop.Value.ToString());
               strList.Add(data);  
           }
           WriteObject(strList);
       }
   ```

All of this is part of the `System.Management.Automation` assembly, which is anyway required, when writing a cmdlet in C#